# How to use map function and render list in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, multidimensional-array

I was trying to load this array and render it as a table using map function how can I do it.
The array response is from `useState`.

I have tried using list indexing and rendering the array as a table but the array changes its number of columns and rows dynamically so indexing does not work as the number of columns and rows keep on changing.

Sample image is shown below:
[image]

what I have tried

```js
 {arrayData.map(function (item) {
  return item;
 })}
```

and got output like
[image]

```js
let array = [
    [
14.203298568725586,
5.916393756866455,
15.5038480758667,
15.5038480758667,
15.5038480758667
],
[
20.115657806396484,
7.724868297576904,
19.88268280029297,
19.88268280029297,
19.88268280029297
],
[
14.476829528808594,
6.237934112548828,
13.77694320678711,
13.77694320678711,
13.77694320678711
],
[
14.203298568725586,
5.916393756866455,
15.5038480758667,
15.5038480758667,
15.5038480758667
],
[
14.203298568725586,
5.916393756866455,
15.5038480758667,
15.5038480758667,
15.5038480758667
],
]
```

Comment: What determines the values in the left column that aren't shown in the data? Headings and colors also

Comment: What do you mean left column? If you are talking about letters there is no need

Comment: colors are changed interactively from 0 to 100 scale @charlietfl

Comment: Yes I am talking about the letters. If there is no need, why are they shown? It would be best you [edit] the question so there is no ambiguity. Please also show what you have tried. SO is not a free code writing service. You simply need a map for rows and an inner map for cells

Comment: @charlietfl Actually the letters are from input fields and the array I have shown above is the output array prediction of a rest-api of the input fields.

Comment: @charlietfl I have edited the image

Comment: using map function and iterating over multidimensional array solved my problem thanks

Answer (score 1):

The name of your array and the what you're trying to map do not match.

So

```
let array
```

Should be:

```
const arrayData
```

For:

```
 {arrayData.map((item) => {
  return item;
 })}
```

To work. Also note arrays should be updated with `useState` so if that's the reason you're using `let`. You don't mention any further code for the grid you're trying to do. Are you passing this to a component in the `map` or building everything when looping?

You also have a multidimensional array so I'm unsure what your goal is when you only show one map.

Comment: using two map functions iteratively looping solved my problem

Comment: Also make sure you add a `key` so you don't get an error, too.